# Class will not serialize in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: 
Type 'NaturalOrderComparator' was not included in the set of types which 
can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could
not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: 
instance = NaturalOrderComparator@35d9c40d
```

I've omitted the package names, but the .class file is located in a package that is accessible to both the client and server code for GWT.

The class in question was pulled from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paour/natorder/master/NaturalOrderComparator.java. I modified the class only to specify that it implements `Comparator<String>` instead of the raw type `Comparator`, and I tried using both `IsSerializable` and `Serializable` interfaces to no avail. Right now it's using `IsSerializable`.

Here are the top 5 lines of the stack trace

```
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:665)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:47)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:29)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is on the call to `Character.isSpaceChar` - suprisingly, [GWT doesn't emulate it](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) and this could lead to this class not being serializable. GWT does however emulate the deprecated [`Character.isSpace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpace(char)) - maybe it can fill its shoes for your needs?

Comment: This was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple Comparator implementation don't return it in an entity/bean object but put it in the .client.* so that it can be compiled. This way both the client and the server can use it. If you have to have it in the object then make it transient so that it won't be serialized. It is common to have another package called shared and make sure your .gwt.xml file has the `<source path='shared' />` so that the compiler will compile classes in the shared package.

Comment: The one advantage I can see to this approach is that the server wants to send the client (or the client wants to send the server) the comparator that should be used for some task. Assuming it is in shared or client so GWT can see it (which I agree, it doesn't seem to be), this should be possible, and probably even reasonable.

Comment: That is where I have it -- the 'shared' package. My company just renamed it to 'restricted' and I forgot the original naming.

Comment: So is the problem that you don't have <source path='restricted' /> in your .gwt.xml file? Did this solve your problem?

Comment: That isn't the issue - 'restricted' was already in the .gwt.xml file.